# Why can't my `date` deal with timezones?

Tags: shell, date, coreutils, timezone

I'm having some weird issues with GNU coreutils date v8.4 (CentOS) that aren't occurring in v8.21 (Ubuntu/Mint).

On v8.4, I get the following output (I'm in PST):

```
$ date --version | head -n 1
date (GNU coreutils) 8.4
$ date -d '2014-11-08'
Sat Nov  8 00:00:00 PST 2014
$ date -d '2014-11-08T00:00:00'
Fri Nov  7 09:00:00 PST 2014
```

I'm assuming it's trying to timezone-correct for UTC, even though I didn't request it and this behavior doesn't occur on my local Linux Mint machine.

Okay, so I'll add a timezone specifier, as specified by [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). On my machine:

```
$ date --version | head -n 1
date (GNU coreutils) 8.21
$ date -d '2014-11-08T00:00:00-0800'
Sat Nov  8 00:00:00 PST 2014
$ date -d '2014-11-08T00:00:00-08:00'
Sat Nov  8 00:00:00 PST 2014
```

Great. But on CentOS:

```
$ date --version | head -n 1
date (GNU coreutils) 8.4
$ date -d '2014-11-08T00:00:00-0800'
date: invalid date `2014-11-08T00:00:00-0800'
$ date -d '2014-11-08T00:00:00-08:00'
date: invalid date `2014-11-08T00:00:00-08:00'
```

**EDIT**: Another one that doesn't work, using `date`'s own output:

```
$ date -d "$(date -Ihours)"
date: invalid date `2014-11-08T13-0800'
```

The following *does* work:

```
$ date -d '2014-11-08 00:00:00 -08:00'
Sat Nov  8 00:00:00 PST 2014
```

but, due to completely unrelated requirements, I can't have any spaces in my date string.

I'm quite perplexed. I looked for [recent changes to `date`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/log/?qt=grep&q=date%3A) but didn't see anything that looks promising.

My question: **How can I get `date` to either not change my timezones at all (preferable), or accept timezone input from a human-readable string without spaces?**

Comment: @Costas mmm, close, but I don't think so. I would rather have it be timezone-agnostic instead of picking a specific timezone. Just "use local time everywhere."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check again the link you [posted](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/log/?qt=grep&q=date%3A),  there's a commit message:

```
date: support parsing of ISO-8601-with-"T" dates
```

It was implemented in coreutils 8.13 (see [changelog](http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=6937)).

Comment: If it was implemented in v8.13, then why does behavior differ between v8.21 and v8.4?

Comment: 1. Because 8.4 < 8.13 < 8.21 and 2. Yes, that's only a test case, the actual implementation is in `lib/parse-datetime.c`

Comment: Oh! I had assumed that v8.13 meant v8.1.3. Thanks for the clarification.